# Regular expression - I'll Need to match last instance of backslash within a path using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Need match (exactly) the last instance of backslash within a path using regex.
e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.20913.0\12345`
I’ll need the regex to point me to `\` just before the `12345`
Tried using `\\[^\\]$` however it will result with `\12345`.

Comment: In which script/tool you want this?

Comment: What language are you using? Some don't have access to the full regex tool set.

Comment: its the built in regex within the Notepad++ search option Im trying to match patterns within huge text file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested in Notepad++

```
\\(?=[^\\]*$)
```

Finds a `\`, then does a positive lookahead to check that every character before the line end is not another `\`.

Comment: no problem, please accept as the correct answer by clicking tick next to the answer since currently the top voted answer is an incorrect one

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ uses the PCRE engine (see [here](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/)).

Therefore using a zero-width positive look-behind (ie. match must be preceded by a pattern) should work:

```
(?<=\\)[^\\]+$
```

That needs to match at least one character after the last backslash, if you want to allow zero (match might be empty) then replace the `+` with a `*`.

Additional: full PCRE reference is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), relevant section is under "[Lookbehind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.lookbehind)" [*sic*].

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response however it didn't worked - Ive also tried this regex (found it somewhere within this forum).